# How to recognize original group from unified set of polygons in R

Tags: r, union, sf

I have simple question. How can I know the original group after apply `z = sf::st_union(x, y)`?

I have 2 sets: `length(x[[1]])` = 4253, `length(y[[1]])` = 91. Finally, I have `z` of lenght 411 but don't know which polygons came from which input set, `x` or `y`. At the end, I need to leave the `x` group only.

Can I set some attribute for `x` and `y` before union? If so how? Maybe there's simpler way to achieve it?

Comment: Can you make a  minimal reproducible example? Use either standard data sets or make some simple polygons. Otherwise we all spend time making examples before we can answer them.